# Evaluating $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\exp\left(n\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{20n}\right)\right)$

Tags: limits

How to calculate limit of the following function?$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\exp\left(n\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{20n}\right)\right)$$
Can anybody give me detailed steps?

Thanks

Comment: You have $e^{a\ln(b)}.$ Can you see another way you can write that? From there, does the limit look familiar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We know the fact that $\ln(1+x)=x+O(x^2)$ for $x\to 0$.

Since $n\to \infty,$ then $\ln (1+\frac{1}{20n})=\frac{1}{20n}+O(n^{-2})$. It follows that $n\ln (1+\frac{1}{20n})=\frac{1}{20}+O(n^{-1})$ for $n\to \infty$.

Hence $$e^{n\ln (1+\frac{1}{20n})}=e^{1/20}e^{O(n^{-1})}.$$

Since $n\to \infty$ it implies that the desired limit is $e^{1/20}$.

Comment: Good answer, but given how likely it is that the question could just be homework, I'd advise you to give hints instead so that they can be pointed in the right direction but still learn by solving the problem themselves.

Comment: @ZFR many thanks

Comment: @StephenDonovan no, it's not my homework, just for fun, reviewing what I learned more than 20 years ago.

Comment: @Ben Understood, but we can't tell that from the question alone

Comment: @StephenDonovan anyway, also thank for your hint